# Is it possible to write a scala macro whose returntype depends on argument?

Tags: macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

For a DSL I would like to be able to do something like:

```
object Creator { 
   def create[T](s :String) :Foo[T] = macro createImpl[T]
   def createImpl[T](c :Context)(s :c.Expr[String]) : c.Expr[Foo[T]] = {
        reify(new Foo[Any]())
   }
 }
```

My problem is to replace the `Any` in reify with something that will return the correctly parametrized version.

(above I use a string argument, but in the final version I plan to use the companion object of class T as a marker to know the argument-type of a Function1[T,Unit])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:
a) write `new Foo[T]()` instead of `new Foo[Any]()` (easy)
b) pass in the macro a representation of type `T`, namely, a value of type `AbsTypeTag[T]`, by declaring the parameter `T` using a context bound: `[T: c.AbsTypeTag]`.

Here's code which I tested in Scala 2.10.0-M7. **Edit**. In 2.10.0-RC1 `AbsTypeTag` has been renamed to `WeakTypeTag`. Everything else about macros and type tags remains the same.

Creator.scala:

```
import language.experimental.macros
import reflect.macros.Context
class Foo[T]
object Creator {
  def create[T](s: String): Foo[T] = macro createImpl[T]
  def createImpl[T: c.AbsTypeTag](c: Context)(s: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Foo[T]] = {
    import c.universe._
    reify(new Foo[T]())
  }
}
```

MacroClient.scala:

```
object Main extends App {
  println (Creator.create[Int](""))
}
```

Note that if you omit the type parameter, you will get a weird error:

```
scala> Creator.create[Int]("")
res2: Foo[Int] = Foo@4888884e

scala> Creator.create("")
<console>:12: error: macro has not been expanded
              Creator.create("")
                      ^
```

You also write:

> (above I use a string argument, but in the final version I plan to use
>   the companion object of class T as a marker to know the argument-type
>   of a Function1[T,Unit])

but if I get it right, this sounds like a bad idea. Instead of writing `Creator.create[T](otherArgs)`, the call syntax would be something like `Creator.create(T, otherArgs)`, not a big advantage (if any). But you can't even get the latter syntax: if `class A` and `object A` are companions, their types are not related: the first has type `A`, the second has type `A.type` where `A` is the companion object and not the type of class `A`.

---

**Update**: how to get the `Creator create Foo` syntax to work and return an instance of `Foo`, if you have control over `Foo`.
Since you ask about the `Any` type argument to `reify`, I assume you are asking about the type argument. That makes only sense if you want the **static** return type of `Creator.create` to be `T` and not `Any`; otherwise, you should clarify your question.

The problem here has little to do with macros. `Creator create Foo` passes the object `Foo` to `Creator.create`, whose declaration needs to express, given `Foo.type`, the type `Foo` through a type expression. Type expressions in Scala are quite limited - they can't use reflection, for instance. But given a type, they can select its type members.

```
trait Companion[Class]
//How to declare a companion
class Foo
object Foo extends Companion[Foo]
/*I'm cheating: an implementation of Companion does not need to be a true Companion. You can add documentation to explain how Companion is supposed to be used. */
object Bar extends Companion[Foo]
//But this is also useful - you can't create your own companion objects for pre-existing types, but you can still create the right instances of Companion:
object pInt extends Companion[Int]
object Creator {
  //T with Companion[S] is needed to workaround a type inference bug (SI-5298) and allow S to be correctly inferred.
  def create[S, T <: Companion[S]](obj: T with Companion[S]): S = ???
}
```

This is limited since you need to alter the companion object, but I'm pretty sure you can't do better. I know no way, **in a type expression** (what you can use in place of `S` when declaring the return type of `create`) of getting from a companion object to its associated class type in general, and I don't think there's one.

Now, changing the above to use macros is straightforward:

```
import language.experimental.macros
import reflect.macros.Context
class Foo[T]
object Creator {
  //T with Companion[S] is needed to workaround a type inference bug (SI-5298) and allow S to be correctly inferred.
  def create[S, T <: Companion[S]](obj: T with Companion[S]): Foo[S] = macro createImpl[S, T]
  def createImpl[S: c.AbsTypeTag, T <: Companion[S]: c.AbsTypeTag](c: Context)(obj: c.Expr[T with Companion[S]]): c.Expr[Foo[S]] = {
    import c.universe._
    reify(new Foo[S]())
  }
}
```

Comment: 1.) I was asking for argument not type parameter ... 2.) `Creator create "Foo"` or rather `Creator create Foo` does have some advantage ... (from a DSL standpoint). 3.) classes and their companions are related, and in there are functions to resolve them in the reflect api.

Comment: I don't get your point 1). For the rest, I'm pretty sure there's no general way to get the `Creator create Foo` syntax - not for arbitrary `Foo`. The relation between a class and its companion cannot be exploited through type inference. I'm going to post a non-general solution separately.

Comment: In the end, I added the non-general solution to the end of the above post.

Comment: Thanks for the update ... Meanwhile I've implemented it in a different way. Basically creating the tree manually instead of using reify. I think your answer is as far as one can go with reify. ... I will write an answer describing what I did in the next days.